# Macbook always at lowest brightness

Tags: display, screen

I have a Early 2011 Macbook pro. A few days ago, I turned on my computer and it was on the lowest brightness setting (almost pitch black).

FYI, about a year ago I spilled beer on my keyboard and a few keys stopped working, including F2. Therefore, to fix it, I plugged it into my external monitor and readjusted the brightness from the System preferences. Nothing changed!

If I look closely at the screen, I can see that it's still working. I'm thinking (hoping?) it's just a bug. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: I'm sure the fermented hops and barley (corn? rice?) are the source of the problem here. I'm not sure there's much help to be found. You've already done a major troubleshooting step and it is obvious (to me) that it is a hardware problem.

Comment: @IconDaemon I should have mentioned it, but I spilled that beer more than a year ago! I don't see why it would have an effect on my hardware only now...

Comment: @IconDaemon If it's a hardware problem, knowing that the screen itself is working, what would I need to change?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with IconDaemon's comment, so don't think there's much help you're going to find here.

However, one thing you *could* try is resetting your System Management Controller (SMC). Now, before doing this I should add that while resetting the SMC is usually a totally safe thing to do, you *may* get unwanted results in the case of liquid damage. So, if you have the option of using your MBP with an external display and keyboard, you may want to just opt for that.

Another thing you should do is ensure you have a good backup of your data. Not just because you should have a backup anyway, but also because of the liquid damage. Your MBP is at a much higher risk now of just one day not working anymore.

If you'd like to try the SMC reset, follow these steps for doing so on your model of MBP:

1. Shut down your Mac
2. Keep the MagSafe adapter (power cable) **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the **left** side of the built-in keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

I'm assuming, of course, that the **left** <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd> keys still work.

Comment: Left `control` does not work. I remapped it to right `option` but that does not work when resetting my SMC. Is there an option to restart computer so it resets the SMC automatically (i.e. through the terminal)?

Comment: Aah, well, that's a whole new question I'm afraid. No, it's not possible via Terminal. If you're comfortable opening up your MBP and have the right tools, you could remove the battery and then reconnect it and this will reset the SMC. If this is not something you're comfortable with, then you _may_ be able to use the SmcFlasher.efi for your MBP. If you can't find another Q&A here that covers resetting the SMC without a keyboard, them you should ask another question about this. However, ensure you provide the **exact** details of your MBP (early-2011 MBP isn't enough).